# Discordjs adding/subracting money randomly

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I need help with Discordjs. I have an economy system but idk how to remove/add money randomly!

Basically, I want the command to randomly give money, but has a chance it will take away money.

Here is the code I use for money...

```
let money = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 1;
db.add(`money_${msg.guild.id}_${user.id}`, money)
db.subract(`money_${msg.guild.id}_{user.id}, money)
```

Comment: Hi. Is it ok, that the closing ` is missing in the 3rd line?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Math.random` for another random number between 0.0 and 1.0 and use it to determine whether to add or subtract

```js
let money = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 1;
let shouldAdd = Math.random() >= 0.5;
let user = `money_${msg.guild.id}_${user.id}`;

if (shouldAdd) {
  db.add(user, money);
} else {
  db.subtract(user, money);
}
```

If you want to `add` 90% and `subtract` only 10% of the time then you can use `shouldAdd = Math.random() >= 0.1;` or tweak it however you want